# When should we encapsulate codes to be a "Class"?

Tags: c++, class, oop, encapsulation

I looked back on my code so far and found that I rarely wrote `class`. Or, in other words, I don't see the value of using them. I mean, almost everything in coding, I can work them out without using classes by just writing functions and group them into different `.h/.cpp` files based on their functionalities.

Even after I've participated in several projects, I still do not feel the urgency to do this as progress goes well without big challenges. I am working mostly with C++ (MATLAB sometimes).

Note that, I did use `struct` a lot and I know that struct and class have no big difference for C++. But I only use struct for data-storage (group data together). The data requires no flow control (i.e. getters/setters that maintain or protect an internal state) nor starts acquiring any major functionality.

Maybe I am missing somewhere about basic things about **OOP**. So when should we encapsulate our codes using classes? Can anyone share your opinions?

Comment: Depends on the language. Good luck writing Java without classes.

Comment: @sftrabbit Focused on C++ recently.

Comment: I think your question should exclude Java. You really can't avoid writing classes in Java (at least I can't think of a situation where it can be avoided).

Comment: `struct`s and `class`es are identical except for access in C++. Maybe you should refine what you mean by "class" if you do use a lot of structs.

Comment: @ChthonicProject Yes, you are right. Excluded now.

Comment: Classes are just another form of encapsulation abstraction - some prefer closures instead. OO analysis and design is just a popular way of getting things done

Comment: What are you going to do when you need to implement inheritance or polymorphism?  How will you do that with a struct? Perhaps your applications simply do not require this additional layer of abstraction.

Comment: You're missing that C++ is dead, you should be using Java and everything is a class. I think. Or maybe I'm remembering an acid trip from my younger days.

Comment: @roybatty `struct` are mainly used for define some complex data types.

Comment: @KerrekSB C++ is dead? In what sense?

Comment: @herohuyongtao. In the acid trip from younger days sense

Comment: "I did use struct a lot, which can be seen as a light-weighted class" You are imagining a difference between `struct` and `class` which does not exist. Instead of asking about C++ keywords `struct` vs. `class` you probably mean to ask about the application of OOP principles like encapsulation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, a `struct` and a `class` are just the same except with a different default access modifier. `struct` members are by default `public`, whereas `class` members are by default `private`. If we think of classes in C++ as being a `class` with encapsulated data members and public member functions that expose functionality related to that data, the following are some good suggestions that you want to use a class:

1. You need to store some state consisting of related items of data, and...
2. You need to impose some invariants on this state or provide some alternative interface to this state.

If you have only suggestion 1, then you probably just want a struct. See [Classes Should Enforce Invariants](http://www.artima.com/intv/goldilocks3.html).

Comment: Many people _[citation needed]_ do tend to treat `struct-key` classes and `class-key` classes differently, though, if only for aesthetics.

Answer (score 4):

You can write classless code in most languages. In Java you would merely use `static` methods and nothing else.

Using C/C++ `struct`s binds groups of values together into a unit to form a single component that can be created and manipulated separately.

The moment you discover you need `class`es and instances of classes (generally objects) is the moment you grow up in your coding. With a `class` you bind a number of fields together (as with `struct`s) but here you attach `method`s to them too. You are now working with objects that have structure **and** function.

Once that step is complete you discover a whole new world of programming where you put these objects inside other objects or into `queue`s for transport or in `map`s and `set`s for storage and then you discover that a `map` and a `set` and a `queue` is in itself an object with its own `class`.

In summary - working with just `process` is like building your house with sand. Working with `struct`s is building your house with sticks. Working with `class`es allows you to instantiate `object`s and manipulate them as entities - build your house with stone - you can then step away from the process you have been so far toiling with and begin to consider the architecture of your system.

Comment: `struct`s can have member functions. There is no difference. You get a class no matter which keyword you use.